# How to get connection pool statistics from Teiid resource adapter?

Tags: teiid

I have resource adapter in wildfly-teiid-server with xml

```
                <resource-adapter id="salesforcefour" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <module slot="main" id="org.jboss.teiid.resource-adapter.salesforce-41"/>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="org.teiid.resource.adapter.salesforce.SalesForceManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/sfDS41" enabled="true" connectable="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="sfDS41">
                            <config-property name="connectTimeout">30000</config-property>
                            <config-property name="password"></config-property>
                            <config-property name="URL">https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/45.0</config-property>
                            <config-property name="requestTimeout">120000</config-property>
                            <config-property name="username"></config-property>
                            <pool>
                                <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                                <initial-pool-size>5</initial-pool-size>
                                <prefill>true</prefill>
                                <use-strict-min>true</use-strict-min>
                                <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                            </pool>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                </resource-adapter>
```

For checking that connection pool really get active connections I need get statistics.

I tied to execute jboss-cli.sh and commends

```
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=salesforcefour:write-attribute(name=statistics-enabled,value=true)

/subsystem=resource-adapters/statistics=statistics/connection-definitions=java\:\/sfDS41:read-resource(include-runtime=true)
```

But get error

```
Failed to get the list of the operation properties: "WFLYCTL0030: No resource definition is registered for address [
    ("subsystem" => "resource-adapters"),
    ("statistics" => "statistics"),
    ("connection-definitions" => "java:/sfDS41")
]"
```

How to check connection pool statistics or just get current active connections count?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from https://github.com/teiid/teiid/pull/1335

For non-jdbc resource adapters it is specified on the pool for the given connection definition:

/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=salesforcefour/connection-definitions=sfDS/statistics=pool:write-attribute(name=statistics-enabled, value=true)

You just need to substitute in the name of the connection definition you used - that is the logical name, which is likely not the jndi name. You can auto complete on subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=salesforcefour/connection-definitions= to see your connection definition names. You should then be able to read the pool statistics against that connection definition name.